# Having problems cancelling a Socket and/or threads

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

In my Code I have two Sockets:

```
private ServerSocket servSock;
private DatagramSocket dataSock;
private ExecutorService threadPool;

// In the constructor this happens
this.threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);
this.servSock = new ServerSocket(this.tcpPort);
this.dataSock = new DatagramSocket(this.udpPort);
this.userResponseStream.println("DEBUG: Successfully created Sockets\n"
                                                + "TCPSocket running on Port: " + this.servSock.getLocalPort() + "\n"
                                                + "UPDSocket running on Port: " + this.dataSock.getLocalPort() + "\n");

// Create a thread which accepts connections on the ServerSocket
this.threadPool.execute(new TCPThread(this.servSock, this.threadPool, this.users, this.logged, this.nodes));

// Create a thread which listens for isAlivePackets
this.threadPool.execute(new UDPThread(this.dataSock,this.nodes));
```

Im not sure if is necessary to show the implementation for the threads, but if so please tell me so.

Anyway so far it all seems good, one threads gets started listening for incoming TCP Connections on the Server Socket and one thread gets started listening for UDP Packages on the DatagramSocket.

Here is the DEBUG output i got until this time:

```
DEBUG: Successfully read information from properties
TCP Port: 14710
UPD Port: 14711
Timeout: 3000
checkPeriod 1000

DEBUG: Successfully created Sockets
TCPSocket running on Port: 14710
UPDSocket running on Port: 14711

DEBUG: Started new TCP Thread, waiting for TCP Connection
DEBUG: Started new UDP Thread, waiting for isAlive Messages from Nodes on Port 14711
DEBUG: Started Thread for checking if Node is timeout every 1000 milliseconds
DEBUG: All Threads successfully created, now waiting for incoming commands
```

(Remember that most of the DEBUG outputs are not listed in the code, since I just showed an excerp)

So now here is what causes me problems, I wrote an exit method which should shutdown all the sockets and threads running, here is the code of that method:

```
public String exit() throws IOException {
        // Free all resources

        // Stop Timer
        this.oCheck.cancel();
        System.out.println("DEBUG: Stopped Timer");

        // Stop Threads
        this.threadPool.shutdown();;
        if( this.threadPool.isShutdown() ) {
            System.out.println("DEBUG: Shutdowned the threadpool");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Something went wrong shutting down the threadpool, Try again");
            return "FAILURE";
        }

        // Cancel TCP Socket
        this.servSock.close();
        if( this.servSock.isClosed() ) {
            System.out.println("DEBUG: Canceled TCP Socked");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("DEBUG: Something went wrong canceling the TCP Socket");
            return "FAILURE";
        }

        // Cancel UDP Socket
        this.dataSock.close();
        if( this.dataSock.isClosed() ) {
            System.out.println("DEBUG: Canceled UDP Socked");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("DEBUG: Something went wrong while canceling the UDP Socket");
            return "FAILRUE";
        }

        System.out.println("DEBUG: All resources where succefully freed exiting System now");

        return "SUCCESS";
    }
```

When I run the exit I somehow get into and endless loop and I dont know why, here is the output I get:

```
!exit
DEBUG: Stopped Timer
DEBUG: Shutdowned the threadpool
DEBUG: Canceled TCP Socked
DEBUG: Canceled UDP Socked
DEBUG: All resources where succefully freed exiting System now
Socket closed
Socket closed
null
Socket is closed
Socket closed
null
Socket is closed
Socket closed
null
```

The last three outputs keeps repeating over and over again
I am wondering where those outputs comes from? I guess that some Threads are still running trying to use the sockets which are closed already.

In my UDPThread this happens:

```
while( true )   {
            this.sock.receive(packet);
            ...
}
```

My TCPThread using a similar loop, so I think that the Threads didnt stop properly.

Thanks in advance for anybody reading throw this and trying to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is incorrect:

```
// Stop Threads
this.threadPool.shutdown();
```

This command does not stop threads, that are in run state. It marks executor to decline all new tasks from execution and cancel not-started tasks in the queue.

You should either stop your handlers by separate shared flag (e.g. `AtomicBoolean shutdown = new AtomicBoolean(false);`) or use `threadPool.shutdownNow()` for interruption of active threads.

Comment: I tried the `threadPool.shutdownNow()` already but I doesn`t change anything

Comment: this means only the fact your TCPThread and UDPThread does NOT handle interruptions. try the second approach, it should help.

Comment: Could you explain the second approach a little bit more? I dont understand exactly how I should use this AtomicBoolean variable

Comment: without threads code? hm... let me guess. your threads have some loop. on each loop iteration you should check this variable is not set to true. this variable should be initialized in main method and should be shared across all created threads. on shutdown - mark it into true.

Comment: Ok it works now, thank you!! I still get 'Socket closed
Socket closed
null' one time. But I think thats because the variable might be read one more time as true, when the socket is already cancelled.